# Processing object on javascript

Tags: javascript, ethereum

I have interesting object on JavaScript which I receive from 3rd party library method call. The data structure looks like this:

```
{ name: 'askForHelp',
  types: [ 'uint256', 'address', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'uint256' ],
  inputs: 
   [ <BN: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff915b27d9>,
     '9e8b197ec64ff341b6f942852169c280c2c7cc80',
     <Buffer 52 65 61 63 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
     <BN: a>,
     <BN: a> ] }
```

I have to process this input array. My point of interest now is inputs[3]:

```
<Buffer 52 65 61 63 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

This element is object. Print to console gives us this result:

```
console.log()
React
```

If I will convert it into JSON it looks different:

```
JSON.stringify(inputs[3])
{"type":"Buffer","data":[82,101,97,99,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

It I transform it into the String, it has another representation:

```
String(inputs[2])
"React\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

What is the proper way to process this data structure? Why does this object view behave itself so different?

Comment: `console.log(new Buffer([82,101,97,99,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).toString())` -> React

Comment: Thank you. How do you access data you put into Buffer constructor?

Comment: Fifured out. Thanks!

Comment: The question still in way to remove unfilled bytes from array -- this '\u0000' in string representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close my own question I used Buffer object proposed by @baao with regexp to cut null characters

```
    var buffer = new Buffer(data).toString();
    var result = buffer.replace(/\0/g, '');
```